# monotouch youtube json parsing using newtownsoft.json

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, youtube-api, monodevelop

I have been trying to parse a youtube request using the Newtownsoft.JSON reference within MonoDevelop/MonoTouch, it runs the request but sends back an empty LIST.  Any Suggestions on how to parse this, and deal with the nested tags which I believe to be causing the main issue?

Basic structure of nested tags:

```
"id": "",
"uploaded": "",
"updated": "",
"uploader": "",
"category": "",
"title": "",
"description": "",
"thumbnail": {
    "sqDefault": "",
    "hqDefault": ""
}
```

public static void GetVideos()
        {
            try
            {

```
            lock (locker)
            {
                VideoDataCallStarted(null, EventArgs.Empty);

                string result = GetData(APIConstants.apiGetYoutube);

                if (result != "")
                {
                    var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataStores.VideosCollection>(result);

                    VideoDataCallComplete(j, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("APIInterface.GetVideos() Returned Null Results");
                    VideoDataCallComplete(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Exception in APIInterface.GetVideos() : " + ex.Message);
            VideoDataCallComplete(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you supply the code you are using to parse the JSON?

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/ 
Make your classes using this.
var jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(myJSONString);

Comment: Code being used for other json objects is simple, dealing with no nested tags, and using deserialize to add to list (added to edited version above)

Comment: Have you verified via somewhere like www.jsonlint.com that you json is, in fact, valid for this instance? Also, does your `DataStores.VideosCollection` object actually match the structure for that JSON? I know that these are really simple questions, but they are usually the first to cause problems.

Comment: Isn't Json.Net open source? If need be, you could add the whole project and a reference to it instead of just the DLLs. This way, you could step through it and see exactly where it is having the issue deserializing.